# Compare 2 tables and find non duplicate entries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. I want to check if columns of table 1 don't have duplicates in columns of table2.

Here is how the search should work! [image: searching duplicate rows]

If no duplicates are found, I want to get the row name from table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, this is what you want.

```
SELECT 
    t1.name 
FROM 
    Table1 t1 
WHERE 
    t1.name 
NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT t2.name 
        FROM Table2 t2
        JOIN t1 
        ON t2.name = t1.name
    )
```

Comment: could you give me a sheme of your tables and specify what fields you want to not to be equal?

Comment: Oh wait, i think it might be working now, i tried with "IN" instead of "NOT IN"

Comment: But if you take IN you actually get the duplicates.

Comment: Alright i tried it with "NOT IN" and the result was all rows of table1

Comment: what rows do you have in each table? give me some more information ;)

Comment: Maybe try out this: `NOT IN (SELECT t2.name FROM Table2 t2 JOIN t1 ON t2.name = t1.name)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a column (or columns) that you will use to "match" the rows, to determine whether they are "duplicates".

I'm going to assume (absent any schema information), that the column name is `id`.

An "anti-join" pattern is usually the best performing option:

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT
  JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

(Performance is dependent on a whole bunch of factors.)

Your other options are to use a NOT EXISTS predicate:

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM table1 a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM table2 b
          WHERE b.id = a.id
       )
```

Or, use a NOT IN predicate:

```
SELECT a.id
  FROM table1 a
 WHERE a.id NOT IN
       ( SELECT b.id
           FROM table2 b
          WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL
       )
```

The generated execution plan and performance of each of these statements will likely differ. With large sets, the "anti-join" pattern (the first query) usually performs best.